# Image.network loadingBuilder's loading progress event is null

Tags: image, flutter, loading, user-experience

I'm trying to use the [`Image.network`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.network.html) constructor's `loadingBuilder` argument.

While the image loads, I want to show a `CircularProgressIndicator` with its value set to the ratio of downloaded divided by the expected file size. I expected I could do this using the [`ImageChunkEvent`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ImageChunkEvent-class.html) parameter's `cumulativeBytesLoaded`, `expectedTotalBytes`.

I found a [sample](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/loadingBuilder.html) in the documentation:

> The following sample uses `loadingBuilder` to show a `CircularProgressIndicator` while an image loads over the network.

```
Image.network(
  'https://example.com/image.jpg',
  loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child, ImageChunkEvent loadingProgress) {
    if (loadingProgress == null)
      return child;
    return Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
        value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null
            ? loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded / loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes
            : null,
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

But the issue is that the `loadingProgress` is always `null`, so the whole `loadingBuilder` charade I'm doing is for nothing.

Why is `ImageChunkEvent loadingProgress` not passed to the `loadingBuilder` function with real values?

Comment: I was just trying the same thing (also loading an image over the network) and my code looks exactly like yours. I just noticed that if it takes a while (like close to 1 second), it doesn't show the loading indicator, guess it's too short an amount of time before the image comes in.

Comment: I faced your problem after 4 years :) Even the fluter sample doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

i found the solution after 3 years

```
loadingBuilder:(context, child, loadingProgress) {
  if (loadingProgress != null) {
     print(loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded);
     return CircularProgressIndicator(
             value: loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded /
             loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes!);
  }
  return child;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I used server-side image cropper, and because of the large photos it took some time for server to process an image and begin sending result. And before Image widget receives any response from a server, loadingProgress is null. And if your image is very small (like in my case), you can see a 1-2 seconds delay and then just an image. Without process indicator.

I think loadingProgress should be non-null from the beginning of the request. Otherwise it makes it required to add an additional check.

Answer (score -1):

Remember to put or gif in `assets` folder and cite it in `pubspec.yaml`

```
FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
  placeholder: 'assets/loading.gif',
  image: 'https://backend.example.com/image.png',
);
```

For more information:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FadeInImage-class.html

Comment: I was not asking about the FadeInImage. I don't want to display an asset, I want to render a widget while the image is loading.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the image has a small size so it instantly loads, try testing with a different larger network image.